# How to delete repeated specific characters

Tags: regex, string, replace, character

I need to replace the "@" with "-" in a string. This is straightforward, but I also need to replace multiple "@@@@@" with just one single "-". Any ideas on how to do the latter with ASP.
Here is an example:

**input string:** 
@Introducción a los Esquemas Algorítmicos: Apuntes y colección de problemas. Report LSI-97-6-T@@@@@@@@09/30/1997@@@@@TRE@

**Desired output:**
-Introducción a los Esquemas Algorítmicos: Apuntes y colección de problemas. Report LSI-97-6-T-09/30/1997-TRE-

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example of what is not working for you so far?

Comment: Old ASP or ASP.NET?

Comment: Well the problem is that if I do: Replace(string,"@","-") I get repeated "-" and I just would like a single "-" when multiple "@" are found in the input string. Thanks

Comment: You are also only instructing to replace a single "@" with a single "-". You need to look into regex quantifiers. http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Actually, DNKROZ posted 2 answers and deleted them with `@+` regex. The [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39288175/3832970) could do I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for classic ASP:

```
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp

 With regEx
    .Pattern = "([\@])\1+|(\@)"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
End With
strMessage = regEx.Replace(str, "-")
```

This will match every occurrence of multiple @@@@ or single occurrences of @

Not sure what language you are using so here's the expression in full with delimiters: `/([\@])\1+|(\@)/g`

**Edit - Even simpler: `/@+/g`**

[image]

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please accept as the answer when possible :)

Comment: Is there something special in the ASP regex engine which does not allow you to just use `@+`?

Comment: No - you're right. I did post an answer at first using `@+` but then deleted it when i thought the OP was looking for something different. However they do produce the same result. Ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            String input = "@Introducción a los Esquemas Algorítmicos: Apuntes y colección de problemas. Report LSI-97-6-T@@@@@@@@09/30/1997@@@@@TRE@";
            String output=Regex.Replace(input,@"\@+","-");
            Console.WriteLine(output);

        }
    }
```